# Leray-Serre spectral sequence for algebraic groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, spectral-sequences

Let $G$ be a semisimple, simply-connected, complex algebraic group. Fix a Borel subgroup $B$ and let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup properly containing $B$. If $M$ is a $B$-module, then we have the Leray-Serre spectral sequence corresponding to the fibration $P/B\to G/B\to G/P$

$E^{p,q}_2=H^p(G/P, H^q(P/B,M))\implies H^{p+q}(G/B,M)$

The notation $H^•(G/B, M)$ means the sheaf cohomology of the sections of the bundle $G\times_B M\to G/B$ and similarly with $G,B,M$ replaced by another group $G$ with closed subgroup $B$ and $B$-module $M$.

My question is, how can the module on the right be seen as a graded version of the module on the left? What is the filtration?

Comment: I'm unclear about the formulation if $M$ isn't acted on by $P$.    (Also, how does the question depend on working in characteristic 0?)

Comment: $H^q(P/B,M)$ means the $q$th sheaf cohomology of the sheaf of sections of $P\times_B M$. I think this has a natural left $P$ action, but I'm not an expert at sheaf cohomology. Characteristic may not be an issue in this generality, which would be interesting.

Comment: (Of course "minimal parabolic" means "minimal parabolic among non-Borels".  Slightly smaller than regular is 'subregular'; I wonder if slightly bigger than minimal is 'superminimal'?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. However, I would also be interested in any parabolic subgroup containing $B$.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking. Even if the spectral sequence collapses at the $E_2$ page, the left and right sides are not isomorphic. The right is the associated graded object of a filtration on the left.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question.

Comment: @Evan:  Sorry to have read the question too hastily when I asked my first question.   (In any case, it's likely that the field doesn't matter so long as it's algebraically closed, since the question seems to be fairly algebraic and general.   I don't have an answer, though I wonder if the old work on Borel-Weil-Bott by Demazure helps.)

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: Yes, Demazure's work is definitely related, and his paper is readable. But in his paper, he refers to works which are much more geometric in flavor, and opaque to me. This is where my confusion begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the vein of @MarkGrant's comment: Since this is a first quadrant spectral sequence, for a given pair $(p,q)$ the individual terms $E_2^{p,q},E_3^{p,q},E_4^{p,q},\ldots$ occurring on each subsequent page of the spectral sequence will eventually reach a stable value $E_\infty^{p,q}$. (The larger $p+q$ is, the more pages of the spectral sequence it may take for $E_r^{p,q}$ to reach its stable value.) In general $E_\infty^{p,q}$ will only be a subquotient of $E_2^{p,q}$. Then the statement that the spectral sequence converges to $H^*(G/B,M)$ means that $H^{p+q}(G/B,M)$ admits a decreasing filtration $F^* H^{p+q}(G/B,M)$ with
$$F^p H^{p+q}(G/B,M) / F^{p+1} H^{p+q}(G/B,M) = E_\infty^{p,q}.$$
If you happen to know that the spectral sequence collapses at the $E_2$-page, and hence for all $p,q$ that $E_2^{p,q} = E_\infty^{p,q}$, then this tells you how to think of the $H^p(G/P,H^q(P/B,M))$ as the filtration layers of $H^{p+q}(G/B,M)$.

Comment: Thanks! That helps clear up some confusion. I'd be really interested to know what this filtration looks like in the case I'm describing.